# Video View not working under Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-videoview

There seems to be a problem in VideoView which doesn't work under Proguard. The following screen comes when a video is being started.

[image: VideoView Not Working in Proguard]

The code for Video View is as follows:

```
        mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.hide();
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video_animation);
        Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.splash_min);
        video_animation.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video_animation.setVideoURI(uri);
        video_animation.requestFocus();

        video_animation.start();
```

Also there is no specific ProGuard setting added for VideoView to run.

Excerpts of build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            resValue "string", "FB_APP_ID", getFbAppKey()
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            resValue "string", "FB_APP_ID", getFbAppKey()
        }
    }
```

Also there are product flavours being used just to manipulate with the application ID.

Comment: Put your build.gradle file plz.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

add keep.xml in raw folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/splash_min"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant to you, but it might be useful for other people. I had the same issue. In my case, the root cause is something to do with one of my library I used and proguard config.

So, I got this error when building an apk with proguard.

[image]

The way I tried to eliminate that error was by adding `-ignorewarning`. The error was solved but it made my video can't be played.

There are 2 ways to solve this issue:

1. remove `shrinkResources true` from gradle

   or
2. remove `-ignorewarning` and fix the warnings generated by your library.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the URI of your video. In fact I think that the problem is with this line:

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.splash_min);
```

Try to log `"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash_min` and find out if it point to a correct location. If not (which I think it won't), you have to add rules to your proguard to keep the location as you expect.

**EDIT:**

The problem is when you enable proguard, the package name changes too. `getPackageName()` will give you the right package name in app, but after enabling proguards it is changed. So your URI won't point to a right location. You should exclude your package name in your proguard rules.

Comment: URI when App is running under ProGuard: android.resource://com.urbanwand.diner.staged/2131034118

Without Proguard: android.resource://com.urbanwand.diner.staged/2131034118

So there is no change whatsoever. But the video is getting played without Proguard

Comment: Post your build.gradle file please.

Comment: Can you try to avoid progard from being applied to the mediacontroller class

Comment: @BachiriTaoufiqAbderrahman : Is there any specific rule to keep Media Controller Class ?

Comment: @A.Badakhshan:  If you read my comment, I logged the URI in both the cases & the packageName remains same , but the video doesn't get played when ProGuard is enabled.

Comment: The URI is correct, but your file is not there since the real package name is changed on the device. Just keep the package name from changing.

Answer (score -2):

There was an issue with the URI which was getting parsed using getPackageName() & the path of the video file. The solution is to write the path of video file inside double quotes rather than using R.raw.file_name as ProGuard seems to restrict the file access from using R.**

The updated URI is :

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/file_name");
```

So this is how it works. Although this increases the size of the apk , but this is the only option which is working just fine.

Feel free to make this answer more informative.